# Woocommerce автодополнения полей адреса на страгице checkout

Tags: woocommerce

Есть несколько плагинов, которые умеют помогать заполнить все поля адреса одновременно. Например по zip code.

Я хочу иметь возможность подсказки отдельно по полям - штат, город, улица.

Можно ли это сделать?